# Not able to connect to local workspace with VSTS by TFS in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, tfs, azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I am not able to connect to local workspace with VSTS by TFS in Selenium WebDriver. Below error will pop up

> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing TFS Server information for https://xyz-ortho.visualstudio.com/".
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,29463340]
>   Message: Connection reset

I followed below steps:

1. Click on plug in i.e connect to team projects
2. Select the project and click on finish
3. Refreshing TFS server till 40% and stuck there for few minutes. After that error pop up will display.

[image]

Note: I tried to reinstall the eclipse, team Foundation server.